# Alfresco - /alfresco and /share difference

Tags: java, alfresco, ecm

So i have installed [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/community/) and have two web applications /alfresco and /share. Whats the difference and purposes of these applications? Can one application exist without the other?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`/alfresco`

This context points you to the Repository application. It's the "core" app, where the content is effectively stored and where all the magic happens. Back in the old times, it was the one and only application, so that when Alfresco introduced Share, it was the only place where to find a UI for some features. Now, Share is missing just a couple things.

Currently, the idea is that this JSF application should be a kind of Admin only interface, only to be accessed whenever Share is missing something. However, if you really love JSF (really?) you can still opt to use this interface to build your Alfresco implementation.

This application is mainly interesting for its features rather than for its UI: all the connections to external systems, like DB, CIFS or IMAP for example, happen from here.

On a side note, the "original" implementation of Alfresco [WCM](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WCM_Overview) is built around this application. Anyway, because of several reasons this implementation of WCM is being phased out, with a [new implementation](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Content_Management) built around Share and its concepts (e.g. Sites) that will grow quite a lot soon.

Don't expect new fancy development on this UI.

---

`/share`

This is usually intended the main UI for end users. No JSF here (thanks, God!), it's a [Spring Surf](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/surf-fwork-intro.html) frontend to Alfresco that focuses on providing a Collaborative environment. Here you will find the concepts of Sites, project/topic focussed containers for content, blogs and wikis.

As all the content is stored via the other application, Share is almost stateless: no DB connection is opened from here, everything is pulled and pushed to `/alfresco` via Alfresco [REST API](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference) and [CMIS](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS).

As already mentioned, the new WCM is leveraged from here, as well as all the common ECM features of Alfresco such as workflows, versioning, document transformations, ACLs and so on. Plus, document previews and thumbnails, Blogs, Wikis, Data Lists, ...

This is most likely the UI Alfresco will continue to improve, adding all the whistles and bells they can come up with.

Comment: thanks for the info, the share UI is definitely the way to go, the uploading of documents needs to be stable though.

Comment: They're working on that, even if the instability you might have experienced is most likely due to bugs in the Adobe flash player or Tomcat 7.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681540/alfresco-file-uploader-how-does-it-work on my uploader issues.

Comment: Hey now, JSF is great!  Spring Surf is bloatware.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding some more information on latest version alfresco 5.0b.

Major changes in alfresco 5.0b is that **Alfresco web client is removed from alfresco**.So there wont be any JSF coding

Repository Architecture is still there, So if you want to deal with core app "/alfresco" is the location which will be used for creating webscript,workflows and other thing.

**Conclusion**

---

- Share will be only used as frontend application.All core portion will
  be on alfresco repository.

---

Comment: Here you can find an interesting blog post by Jeff Potts about what has changed with the introduction of Alfresco version 5 http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2014/11/06/3962

Comment: Interesting.  Where does one go to get node IDs for setting up e-mailers if the JSF portion (which held that information) is gone.  I don't see it added to the share app?

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco:
By a developer point of view I would describe "alfresco" as the backend repository that sums up most of the functionality for which we use ACS. The services that share uses are defined in alfresco.

Share:
Share was introduced so that a person with not so much technical knowledge may be able to get as much as possible out of the ECM. If you are new to share you should look into model manager, smart folders and actions.

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, think of /alfresco as the repository part of Alfresco and /share as the user interface. Keep in mind that Share is now deprecated and will be replaced more and more with something called Alfresco Digital Workspace. For now, they have most of the same functionality except that the old Share uses an older Javascript framework, called "Surf" that integrates with a much older version of Spring. The Alfresco Digital Workspace is created using Angular and is a client that can be run from its own WAR.