# Alfresco file uploader - how does it work?

Tags: alfresco, file-upload

My alfresco install(on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS Server) is failing to upload files via `/share`.  for small files, the progress bar goes to 100% put later fails (after pausing for 2 minutes). There are no exceptions in the logs.

How does the upload process work? Is there a port i need to enable on Linux?

**`EDIT`**

I can upload file on my dev box(Ubuntu 10.10) accessing (http://locahostORip-address:8080/share), it only fails if i copy over to the UAT env.

Comment: it only fails if I copy over to the UAT env? What do you mean by the UAT environment? What is the difference except the Ubuntu version?

Comment: no difference, except that i'm accessing the UAT remotely, i.e. not localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're using the flash-uploader. Is your flash working ok?

There is a way to use the non-flash uploader, but then you can only upload one file at a time.

Comment: If you grab a nightly build, then you can also use HTML 5 drag-and-drop upload too - https://twitter.com/mikehatfield/status/57726539143462913

Comment: Ok (moans), disabled the `cool` flash uploader for the html one with some HTML 5 DnD.

Answer (score 0):

File uploads in share use regular HTML multi part file uploads. There's nothing special about them - if you can browse the share interface then you should have everything set up to let you upload files. No special ports need to be opened.

There are other ways to upload files into Alfresco, such as CIFS and FTP. For those, you do need to enable things. See http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/File_Server_Configuration for details.

As a general thing though, if you're having file upload problems, you're much more likely to see errors in the main repo logs (the /alfresco/ web app) than the share one.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few known issues with the Flash uploader in Share that might be the cause behind the problems you're experiencing:

- if you're using Tomcat 7, please [revert to the 6.x series](http://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-7204)
- if you're on Websphere 7, please consider using a [different AS](http://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-1078)
- if you're on HTTPS using self signed / untrusted certificates, verify your browser is [correctly configured](http://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-6392)